# MDI application issues

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

General description of application:
Main form as MDI Container. On application start, if there is no xml file for database configuration (it is checked in Main form) Main form i call another form as showdialog() to fill all database info to build connection string. Then i close form and open another for login, then i get back to Main form, which has Split Container (2 panels: 1-menu on top, 2-content from child forms).

I open forms with:

```
    private void PlanButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    plan.TopLevel = false;
    KontenerMenu.Panel2.Controls.Add(plan);
    plan.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    plan.Show();
}
```

and close form with:

```
private void Plan_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = false;
    this.Hide();
}
```

Problems i have with app:

1. When i hit Cancel button when i open ShowDialog() form for database app crashes. Cancel button is simply:

```
private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

2. I have problem with clicking button to open/close/open again child forms. When i hit 'X' and want o open, app crashes with exception that it cannot refer to non-existing object

3. I have several buttons when i hit one and then another one it is always below the first one and not on the top

4. For example my form is 200x200 and in right down corner i have button (so location let's say 190x190) and i hit maximize button. My button is still on 190x190 and i would like to have it on down right corner. I couldn't find any property for that. Is there any or i have to write some code for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your questions. Please make them clear.
But as an answer to question #4, there's an anchor property that does what you want.

Comment: 1. problem with cancel button which click event i presented above. When i click app looks like on attached screen. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/718/64241251.png/  <br/>

2. I cannot close and open again child forms. I got exception. Codes above. <br/>
3. I open form1, then open form2. Form2 is hidden behind form1. I would like to have form2 on top <br/>

4. Thanks, it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to exit the application from within the dialog form itself you should return a DialogResult value and test that in the main form.  The cancel button on the dialog doesn't need any code, just set its DialogResult property to 'Cancel' and if you have an Ok button set its DialogResult to 'OK'.

```
DialogForm f = new DialogForm();
DialogResult r = f.ShowDialog();
if (r == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
   Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can immediately see a number of problems with you code, including:

1. If you're going to add controls dynamically using Controls.Add, you should make sure the controls you're adding are dynamically created using new(). I get a sense that you don't have a clear understanding of object lifetimes and the WindowForms control life cycle.
2. The Application.Exit method should be used only in unusual cases. It's purpose is to achieve exactly the result you're observing - to immediately "crash" the application. The easiest way to have a button close a modal dialog is the set the DialogResult property of the button.
3. Winforms has a very elegant system for placement of control on a variable sized window. In order to use this system, you should familiarize yourself with the Anchor and Dock properties that are available on all controls.

It looks like what you're doing is attempting to learn WinForms by trial and error. You can do this, but it will take much longer and be much more painful that getting a hold of a good tutorial, book, or perhaps even attending a class if you can manage it. That will allow you to take these issues one at a time and have a much more enjoyable learning experience.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm trying to learn even C#, by writing app :)
Maybe, i should read first 'Core C#' by S.C. Perry book first :)

Regarding 3. point, maybe i wasn't clear enough. It is not the case of controls, but whole form. In MDI Parent i open childs and there is always first open child form on top, rest clicked are behind it.

Comment: You've brought up many issues in your question and I wasn't trying to address all of them. I'd suggest you try again and plan you questions more carefully. In particular, I would advise you to only ask about one issue in each question instead of trying to cover multiple issues within a single question. There are many questions on this site that discuss the best way to prepare a question that will get good results (for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902994/how-to-ask-programming-questions-correctly).